# Which `EVM` bytecode is actually used to "deposit" the transferred Ether?

Tags: evm, address.transfer, opcode, gas-refund

A quick question. Which `EVM` opcode is actually used to "deposit" the transferred Ether into the contract? From the `EVM` opcode list, there are only two opcodes related to the fund transfer: `balance` and `selfdestruct`, but both of them are used to "read" the fund, not actually modify the fund record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ether that came along with transaction is deposited at smart contract's balance **before** byte code is executed, and it will stay there unless byte code execution will revert the transaction, or unless it will send this ether further.